# R making a table of factors with different categorical levels log linear model

Tags: r, glm

Here is my code trying to make a table:

```
table <- data.frame(expand.grid(
    health = factor(c("support", "oppose"), levels = c("support", "oppose")), + 
    information = factor(c("support", "oppose"), levels = c("support", "oppose")), + 
    gender = factor(c("male", "female"), levels = c("support", "oppose")), 
                    count = c(76, 160, 6, 25, 114, 181,  11, 48)))
```

R is saying `unexpected '=' after info`. my professor did an example just like this in class and his code worked. I'm trying to do a log linear model of the data

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `+`s:

```
table<- data.frame(expand.grid(health=factor(c("support", "oppose"), 
 levels=c("support", "oppose")), information = factor(c("support", 
"oppose"), levels=c("support", "oppose")), gender = factor(c("male", 
"female"), levels=c("support", "oppose")), count=c(76, 160, 6, 25, 114,
 181,  11, 48)))
```

They are likely from copy/pasting the echo of the code in the R console, but get you syntax errors.